# Get accessibility access in SwiftUI / Xcode 12.5

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I want the user to grant the Universal Access permissions in System preferences for my Mac app.

1. I expect the following code to recognize that the app has not the appropriate permissions and prompt the system pop-up "The following application wants Accessibility access" or whatever, but it just returns false:

```swift
            let options : NSDictionary = [kAXTrustedCheckOptionPrompt.takeRetainedValue() as NSString: true]
            let accessibilityEnabled = AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions(options)
```

2. I can manually grant Accessibility access to applications in System Preferences -> Security -> Accessibility, but there, of course, I don't see the app I'm developing in Xcode. How to grant such permissions to an app in development? I tried to generally give permissions to XCode but that doesn't work and `AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions` keeps returning false.

Comment: MacOS did some stuff to remember the answer (to block an app from repeatedly nagging the user). Could it be that you declined it in the past, and are just seeing that "remembered decline" value over and over?

Comment: No, never, it's a brand new app I'm just developing

Comment: Do the log messages in `Console.app` give any clues?

Comment: @pistacchio Did you find the solution for this?